# Update iOS application bypassing AppStore

Tags: ios, updates

In iOS files of bundle in .app directory are not available for writing. But some application (for example Plants vs Zombies 2), always updates by passing AppStore (screenshot below).

What are the approaches do you know to implement it? How they do it?

Screenshot "Plants vs Zombies 2" updating:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They only download assets. You are not allowed to download code to run on your device, therefore they leave the update content assets on the server so that you can download those images to your device through https requests.

These images are then saved in a documents or some other directory where the app can freely access it.

**The app isn't truly updating itself, it's just downloading new assets for the game.**

Comment: What about uncompiled languages: for example js with c++ bindings? We can download it and execute, aren't it?

Comment: Downloading and executing code is not allowed for the App Store and will not pass review. The only place allowed for that is JS in a `UIWebView` container.

Comment: We can do not declare it and hide this process. Does not help?

Comment: I can shoplift and not tell anybody about it, but that doesn't mean they won't find out. Apple is very strict about this and will not allow any instances of running code to slip past their app review process.

Comment: You don't want to mess with Apple restrictions. Or you'll have a bad time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Those apps don't update "themselves". They update data that they then use to run (like level designs, artworks, sounds...). But the core of the app can't change without going through the app store.

Comment: There is of course a line that is fuzzy around this. New assets can often mean new code paths are executed, etc.